# Loading all raster layers in folder using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I would like to load all raster layers with type .xyz which are in a folder into my QGIS Project using PyQGIS and wrote the following function

```
    for lyr in glob.glob(os.path.join(inputDir, "* .xyz")):
        rasterlyr = QgsRasterLayer(lyr , "")
        QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(rasterlyr)
```

I'm getting the following error message:

> QgsProject.addMapLayers(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsRasterLayer'

But according to the [Dokumentation "Cheat Sheet"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/cheat_sheet.html) this should actually work.

Does anyone see the mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(rasterlyr)` with a `s` while you are giving a single raster layer. You need to use the singular version *or* to give a list of layers (even with a single layer in the list).

Either do

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rasterlyr)
```

or

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([rasterlyr])
```

My preference is the first one.